# How to access System.getProperties() when you have converted java project to .Net

Tags: c#, java, .net, htmlunit

I am trying to use HTMLUnit in .Net I followed the example in Steven Sanderson's blog http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/ which works well. However I have encontered the problem mentioned in [How to disable runtime warnings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478383/how-to-disable-runtime-warnings-in-java) where I want to turn down the noise from Log4J.

As stated I need to do the following:-

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog","fatal");
```

But I have no idea how to do this in .Net. Any help would be much appreciated.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The config system is .NET considerably different to that in Java (he said, not having written any Java for over 10 years!).  Take a look here to get you started : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.aspx

You can also write custom config sections/handler for more complex bespoke config scenarios. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: not really I am afraid. I am not really sure how to use the first link to help me and the second link is a 404. I do really appreciate you trying to help me but I am still stuck. I did find http://osdir.com/ml/java.ikvm.devel/2006-07/msg00041.html which I tried but that doesn't seem to work either.